# Split geocoding task

Tags: php, mysql, split, geocode

I'm currently working on a project which needs to geocode locations stored in a mySQL database.

I wrote a small script which imports a CSV into the mySQL database and automatically fills the longitude and latitude fields in each row with a "0.000000".

Now I found a script that checks the database for missing geocodes and updates those. Since [this script](http://imagine-it.org/google/articles/geocode.htm) is a few years old and just worked with Google I fitted it to my needs (should work with Wordpress and Nominatim instead of Google Maps).

Importing the CSV works just fine but when running this script to update about 5200 locations I get a timeout. Unfortunately I can't increase any timeout settings so I need to split task into steps.

How can I accomplish this?

I'm still a bit green behind the ears when it comes to PHP so any help would be appreciated. I already tried splitting the loop by increasing a counter variable which I squared with the number of mySQL rows I need to update. It should refresh the page now every 100 rows but unfortunately it didn't really work. It works for about 500 or so locations but after that - timeout.

Does anybody know a solution?

```
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$connection) {
die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

// Initialize delay in geocode speed
$delay = 0;
function getLnt($address){
    $request_url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=".urlencode($address)."&format=json&addressdetails=1";
    $result_string = file_get_contents($request_url);
    $result_json = json_decode($result_string, true);
    return $result_json[0];
}


// Iterate through the rows, geocoding each address


    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $geocode_pending = true;

        while ($geocode_pending) {

            $street = $row["address"];
            $zip = $row["zip"];
            $city = $row["city"];
            $id = $row["id"];

            $address = $street.', '.$zip.' '.$city;

            $details = getLnt($address);
            $lat = $details[lat];
            $lng = $details[lon];
            $state = $details[address][state];
            $country_iso = $details[address][country_code];

            if (http_response_code() == 200) {     

                // successful geocode
                $geocode_pending = false;

                $query = sprintf("
                    UPDATE locations SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s', state = '%s', country_iso = '%s' WHERE lat = '0.000000' AND lng = '0.000000' AND id = '%s' LIMIT 1;",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($lat), mysql_real_escape_string($lng), mysql_real_escape_string(utf8_decode($state)),mysql_real_escape_string($country_iso),mysql_real_escape_string($id)
                );

                $update_result = mysql_query($query);

                if (!$update_result) {
                   die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
                }

        } else if(http_response_code() == 620) {

                // sent geocodes too fast
                $delay += 100000;

            } else if($details == NULL) {

                // failure to geocode
                $geocode_pending = false;
                echo "Address " . $address . " failed to geocoded. ";
                echo "Received status " . $status . "
                \n";

            }
            usleep($delay);

        }

}
```

Comment: Can't be the problem otherwise I would've been blocked for the remaining day.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add pagination to your location query:

```
// Select all the rows in the markers table
$offset = intval($_GET['offset'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM locations WHERE 1 LIMIT $offset, 100";
```

and then iterate through pages in your browser. You can do it manually, or by using javascript/jquery on another page which will query destination:

```
var locations_count = 1000000;
var offset = 0;
var func = function(){
    $.get('update-location.php', {offset: offset}, function(){
            document.write('<br/>Processed ' + offset + ' records');
            offset += 100;
            if( offset < locations_count )
                setTimeout(func, 100);
            else
                document.write('<br/>Update finished');
    });
};
func();
```

(dont forget to update `locations_count` to your actual number of locations).

**And other solution:**

Dump the table to your local machine and then update it locally and then update the resulting table on server.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this entirely with PHP and fully automatically?

Comment: as I said - copy to local machine, do update and then upload results back - it will be just php.

Comment: Copying it to a local machine is not an option - it has to work on the server.

Comment: if you have access to server over ssh - then you can run your script using php-cli, it has no time limits

Comment: Also not an option. It has to be absolutely fool-proof (client-proof) because it's not me who is handling the data in the end.

Comment: Man, you see that it simply doesnt work as is in a browser, you should agree some compromises. I offered you a JS front-end which would eliminate big chunks issue

Comment: I didn't say that he didn't do a good job and I know I can only learn from others with deeper skills. It just is beyond my knowledge why this can't be solved without Javascript. I'm also grateful for your help, don't get me wrong - I really am. This actually helped me a lot, Vitaly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it can't be done within one call because you experience time limits. So you have to split your job into many calls. In browser you can do many calls only by using javascript.

Comment: But what if I would reload (that would be multiple calls or wouldn't it be?) the page after every 100th iteration of the loop by setting and increasing a counter variable and stop the script if the counter variable matches the number of rows to update or the latter would be zero? Wouldn't that work?